# Use double quote in a wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I want to add an extra double quote in my WordPress shorcode attribute. My shortcode is `[shortcode icon_title="Delta T" icon_des="Une discussion technique de ce paramètre important dans le calcul des circonstances de l'éclipse."]`

I want to add a double quote `(" ")` in a attribute like `icon_des="this is "icon" des"`

But this breaks my `shortcode`.Can anyone help me in this
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use html code for quotes. Check below:

```
icon_des="this is &quot;icon&quot; des"
```

Comment: Works perfect.Thank you very much. @jaydip nimavat

Answer (score -1):

You can use back slashes to extra double code. Try this

```
icon_des="this is \"icon\" des"
```

Comment: This didn't work in my case. WordPress shortcodes do seem to recognise backslash escapes, but not in a predictable way.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/sovuqn